# Sending String to server from client in java

Tags: java, client, server

My Server is not receiving a simple string from client. And displaying 'null'

Client.java

```
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream( ClientSocket.getOutputStream() );
                os.writeBytes("Hello\n");
```

Server.java

```
  DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream( clientSocket.getInputStream() );
   String line = is.readLine(); 
   System.out.print(line);
```

Comment: did you close() or flush() the stream on client side? Otherwise the data may still be in a buffer, waiting to be sent.

Comment: You can refer this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_networking.htm